# Resolution turn to 1024x768 dual monitor in Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, resolution

***Current Scenario:***

---

**OS Detail:**

1. Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 Professional RTM 6.1.7601.18869
2. Service Pack Version: Service Pack 1
3. DirectX: DirectX 11.1

**Hardware Info:**

1. CPU Info: Mobile DualCore Intel Core i5-3320M, 3100 MHz (31 x 100)
2. Laptop Model: Lenovo ThinkPad T430
3. Mainboard Chipset: Intel Panther Point QM77, Intel Ivy Bridge
4. System Memory: (DDR3-1600 DDR3 SDRAM)
5. Memory Details:4 GB DDR3-1600 DDR3 SDRAM
6. Memory Timing:`(11-11-11-28 @ 800 MHz)  (10-10-10-27 @ 761 MHz)  (9-9-9-24 @ 685 MHz)  (8-8-8-22 @ 609 MHz)  (7-7-7-19 @ 533 MHz)  (6-6-6-16 @ 457 MHz)  (5-5-5-14 @ 380 MHz)`

**Video Info:**

1. IGP: Intel HD Graphics 4000
2. Monitor 1: AOC e943Fwk  [19" LCD]
3. Monitor 2: Lenovo LP140WH2-TLF1  [14" LCD]

**Multimedia:**

1. HDMI : Intel Panther Point HDMI @ Intel Panther Point PCH - High Definition Audio Controller [C-1]
2. Audio Adapter: Realtek ALC269 @ Intel Panther Point PCH - High Definition Audio Controller [C-1]

**Storage:**

1. SATA controller: Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller - 1E03
2. Hard Disk: HITACHI HTS725050A7E630 ATA Device  (500 GB, 7200 RPM, SATA-III)
3. Optical Drive: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GT50N ATA Device  `(DVD+R9:6x, DVD-R9:6x, DVD+RW:8x/8x, DVD-RW:8x/6x, DVD-RAM:5x, DVD-ROM:8x, CD:24x/24x/24x DVD+RW/DVD-RW/DVD-RAM)`

**Partitions:**

1. C: (NTFS) 465.7 GB (285.0 GB free)

**HID:**

1. Keyboard: Standard PS2 Keyboard.
2. Mouse: Mouse  HID Compatible
3. Mouse: ThinkPad UltraNav Pointing Device

**Network:**

1. VPN: Check Point Virtual Network Adapter For Endpoint VPN Client.
2. NIC: Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection.
3. Wireless Adapter: Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205.
4. Módem: Standard Modem with Bloetooth link.

---

Pictures

**Monitors Working Fine.**

[image: Desktop Working Fine]

**Monitors with the Anomally.**

[image: Monitors with the Anomally]

---

***Problem detail:***

Im facing a weird situation when im using my system. ive conected a second monitor in extended desktop mode, without any noticeable warning my resolution turns into 1024x768 in both Screens, and when i try to get the resolution back is a fight because it allow me to change the resolution again to 1366x768 in Laptop Monitor, but when i try to set  AOC monitor in 1366x768 both goes into 1024x768 and vice versa, finally they work again but only in 136**0**x768 ,even when switching to 1360x768 it changes back to 1024x768, but is very annoying face this problem every day arround 2 o 4 times daily :(.

Any idea what could be happening?

Any suggestion to point me into the right direction to face the problem?

Every comment help!.

Comment: @Sam no, AOC monitos is plugged via VGA cable + Integrated Laptop Monitor.

Comment: Is there a HDMI output on your laptop?

Comment: yes, i've one, as the post shows.

Comment: Have you tried using that instead?

Comment: @Sam, i've tryed all possible in my current scenario, my scenario havent a Monitor with HDMI, so i have not tryed that because i cant.

Comment: Does your monitor have DVI?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26933/discussion-between-francisco-tapia-and-sam).

Answer (score 0):

Here https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU I found the CRU program. It's free and it gives you the opportunity to change the resolution of all monitors you have with no headaches...